# OpenPyXL coordinate_to_tuple Method Fails on Absolute Addresses

Tags: python, openpyxl

Fairly simple *OpenPyXL* question... how can I change the following line to return the address tuple for an absolute address cell?  I could manually remove the dollar signs, but it seems like that is a dirty work-around for something that seems like a bug in *OpenPyXL*.

```
# The following line results in the error:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   ...
#     coordinates = coordinate_to_tuple('$A$2')
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py", line 202, in coordinate_to_tuple
#     return int(row), _COL_STRING_CACHE[col]
# KeyError: '$A$'
coordinates = coordinate_to_tuple('$A$2')

# The following are all hacky work-arounds to return a tuple (row, col)
# Working hack 1
coords = coordinate_to_tuple('$A$2'.replace('$', ''))
# Working hack 2
coords = range_boundaries('$A$2')[1:3]
# Working hack 3
coords = coordinate_from_string('$A$2')
coords = (coords[1], column_index_from_string(coords[0]))
```

Perhaps there is a method that undoes a call to `absolute_coordinate` that I'm missing in the [OpenPyXL utils documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html)?  Or is the literal dollar sign defined in some constant that is part of the public API?  I'll push forward with hack #1 unless someone suggests a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coordinate_to_tuple()` is an optimised function for handling cell addresses when reading worksheets which can have millions of cells; whereas `coordinate_from_string()` is more generic and suitable for functions and ranges where this style is more frequent. In such cases adding another line to get what you want is perfectly okay (reducing lines is not an aim in Python) and not a hack.

Looking at what is actually used in the codebase, it looks like the `range_…` functions are used where you can expect these kind of addresses but `range_boundaries(coord)[:2]` is probably what you want and will let you handle individual cells and ranges with ease.